# Rails: nested form binded to an object – problems with select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, drop-down-menu, form-helpers

I have a nested form model in my Rails app.  When I go to edit an object in the model, all of my fields (text_area, check_box, etc.) are populated with data from the database except for the select box. How can I get my select box to also populate when I am using the form to edit existing data from the model?

```
<%= form_for @test do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'question_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**_question_fields.html.erb**

```
<fieldset>

  <%= f.text_area :question_text %>

  <%= f.select :correct_answer, options_for_select([['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 4], ['E', 5]]), :prompt => 'Choose the correct answer' %>

  <%= f.check_box :question_check %>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Does field value of correct_answer is saved?

Comment: Yes, it saves in the database. It is an integer field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to send the selected parameter in options_for_select function call.

```
<%= f.select :correct_answer, options_for_select([['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 4], ['E', 5]], :selected => f.object.correct_answer), :prompt => 'Choose the correct answer' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a value for `selected`.

Refer to: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

**Edit:** Can't test it now but I'm pretty sure `select` will take the array of options by itself. So you shouldn't need `options_for_select` here - then `select`should set the *selected* option..
Try this and refer to: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select